# Border radius for buttons

Tags: html, css

I have the next items:

```css
.first {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 15px
}
.second {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<button class="first">click</button>
<button class="second">click</button>
```

Why the second button, even if it has the same border-radius, the corners are different than the first? How to set the border-radius for the second button to be 22px with the same corners as previous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the second button even if it have the same border radius, the
> corners are different than the first?

Because `22px` is a fixed size. If you look precisely the border-radius is exactly the same! Just the width and height differ.

I've created a screenshot of your question. Made two layers with transparency and put the edge from small button over the big button and vice versa.. See how exactly the same the corners are[image]

**A possible solution to make it look the same:** The first button radius is `22px` which is ~half the height of the button.

So to get the "same look" you can set the button radius of the second button to `28px` which is half the size of the second button.

But be careful, if you change the `font-size` or `line-height` this will affect the height!

```css
.first {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 15px
}
.second {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<button class="first percent">click</button>
<button class="second percent">click</button>
```

**Update: Another solution is** because you also kind of set the biggest possible radius you can set a number which is bigger then all the buttons will ever be, something like

```css
.first {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 15px
}
.second {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<button class="first">click</button>
<button class="second">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go with a percentage `border-radius: 40%;` instead of fixed values in px. The percentage will work with relative to the size of the button.

```css
.first {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 40%;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 15px
}
.second {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border-radius: 40%;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<button class="first">click</button>
<button class="second">click</button>
```

Comment: or you could do `border-radius: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999px;` but that's a bit long, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using different Font sizes in buttons that's why buttons border radius is looking different, You can solve this issue using `border-radius : 60px;` in both buttons css and if you want to set same height you can use `min-height`.

```css
    .first {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 15px;

    border-radius: 60px;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
.second {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
.three {
    padding: 12px 35px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 15px;

    border-radius: 60px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Different font size</h2>
<button class="first">click</button>
<button class="second">click</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h2>Same font size</h2>
<button class="three">click</button>
<button class="three">click</button>
```